# Unfortunately, Mail has stopped

Tags: email, crashes, htc-one, stock-email-app

I have an HTC One M8 and am using the stock launcher and am not rooted.

I keep getting the error *Unfortunately, Mail has stopped.* when I try opening the stock HTC mail app.

I have gone into the App Info for the mail app and tried to "Clear cache" but it doesn't look like it's doing anything.

I have also gone to **Settings>Accounts & Sync>Exchange ActiveSync** and unchecked Mail in the account that is using it.

I have also tried rebooting my phone.

Any other tips or advice aside from basically wiping the phone?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a recent occurrence or has it always behaved this way?

Comment: Recent. It just started last night.

Answer (score 1):

A bug may have corrupted the app's data. You could try resetting the 'data' portion instead of just the 'cache'. This would essentially make the app reset to factory default (but only that app, not the rest of the phone).

You would have to redo all of your settings, but the important parts (emails) are on the exchange server, so it wouldn't be too difficult to get back to the way things were.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to clear the "Data" not the cache, if the problem is still persistent or has happened after a recent update then try to roll back to the factory version.